# What does "before" mean here?

Tags: meaning, adverbs

> Kim frequently exhibited her vast knowledge of baseball before complete strangers.

*Before* is usually used to depict a time line, so this use is confusing for me.

Answer (score 10):

*Before*  means *in front of* here. Other examples:

> Kneel before the King!
>
> He didn't have any experience of appearing before a large audience.
>
> Before you is a list of topics we will discuss today.

This meaning of *before* is rather formal.

Comment: At first I thought it was only "formal" because it so often occurs in such forms as [Kneel before Zod!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fFyHTU8tg_0). But you're quite right - even your third example would be *"In front of you..."* in casual speech. It's the same "in front of" meaning as the temporal sense - just that here it's "in front" in space rather than in time.

Comment: It's all relative to the human body and its projections, metaphorical and other. This is treated in Fillmore's chapter on "[Space](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/2-Space.pdf)".

Comment: @John: Yes, I think the connection between *in front of* and *before* is inherent, because in many languages the same word is used for both.

Answer (score 1):

*In front of* is pretty close, but I believe that *for an audience of* is more correct.

Using *in front of* indicates some physical relation, which need not be the case.

Comment: *In front of* also has the meaning of *for an audience of*, doesn't it?

Comment: @slothsberry can you show an example?

Comment: @LouisRhys What! you want an example? *In front* of everyone? :)

Answer (score -1):

Here we "before" used in the physical sense see in an old, familiar nursery rhyme.

```
When the pie was opened,
The birds began to sing;
Wasn't that a dainty dish,
To set before the king?
```