# Using "Before" for audience

Tags: grammar

I am not sure if using "before" is correct here:

> The Stars Music Group did a fantastic job at the University of Kansas
>   **before** a large group of Iranian and American audience.

Is that correct? or should I use

> "in front of"

Comment: What's the problem? why down vote?!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "before" mean here?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57224/what-does-before-mean-here)

Comment: Read the link but I would just contribute a "Yes", your usage of "before" sounds fine in your sentence.

Comment: "Before" is perfectly valid here,  It means essentially the same as "in front of".

Comment: The use of "before" here is normal English, but what follows isn't. You can't refer to ***a group of audience***, regardless of the size of the group, or the nationality of the audience.

Comment: To continue from FumbleFingers pertinent and acute observation, you could say: *before a large audience* OR *before [a mixed audience of](https://www.google.it/search?q=before+a+mixed+audience&oq=before+a+mixed+audience&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=+%22a+mixed+audience+of%22) Iranians and Americans*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see meaning 3 [in Longman's Dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/before_2)

> used to say that something happens where it can be watched by people

Comment: Doesn't this make the question general reference?

Answer (score -1):

One of the many meanings of ***'before'*** is ***'in front of'***.

And if you search the meaning of ***'in front of'*** you'll get the meaning as **'facing someone or a group'** or **'in someone's presence'**. E.g. - ***He shy to speak in front of the crowd. We should not quarrel in front of our children.***

So it is clear that ***'in front of'*** perfectly fits in this situation. But the question is does ***'before'*** fit here?

The uses of ***'before'*** are : ***in the presence of, when confronted by, in front of***, etc. E.g. - ***The prisoner was brought before the judge. The bravely stood before the enemy. He is standing before me.***

Thus we may conclude that though the idiom ***'in front of'*** is *'more'* appropriate than ***'before***' yet we may use ***'before'*** in the above case.